# Rational software architect how to read .h and .cpp files into a new project

Tags: c++, uml, tool-uml

I am new to UML and I am trying to use Rational Software architect to visualize a C++ project.
1) How can I add the existing .h and .cpp files that I have to a new Rational Software architect project in order to see the UML diagram?

2) I see that there is an option in the Rational Software architect to visualize the .h files (I see it in the sample project of version 7), is it the same as the reverse engineering option in this tool?

3) I am developing a C++ program with Visual C++, is the rational Software architect a good choice? or is there a better choice?

4) Any reference to a good User guide or User manual for the Rational Software architect?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried searching the Rational Website?  Search for "IBM Rational Architect".

Comment: Hi Thomas, Yes I have tried, I could not find a good answer until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,
right mouse on the new project name, import-> general file system.
I had problems to find it before because I was looking for the C++ options.